# How to assign instance of a class to Tag in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My Xaml code is in assembly Foo, in namespace Foo.   In assembly FooBar, in namespace Foo.Bar, I have a class called MyClass which contains a parameterless constructor.  In my xaml, I want to create a new instance of MyClass and assign it to Tag.  How can I do this?

I have tried the following:

```
<Application x:Class="Foo.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:foobar="clr-namespace:Foo.Bar;assembly=FooBar"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
  <Application.Resources>
    <foobar:MyClass x:Key="MyClass"/>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

but already at this point I get the squiggly underline that says "The type MyClass does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Foo.Bar;assembly=FooBar", even though it does.

How do I resolve this?  And after I resolve this, How do I write the following?

```
<XamlElement Tag="{??????}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The designer may not be aware of a new class if it wasn't compiled first. Try compiling and running.

Also, if the class is in the same assembly where the XAML is, `assembly=` is not required:

```
xmlns:foobar="clr-namespace:Foo.Bar"
```

To access a resource, use:

```
<XamlElement Tag="{StaticResource MyClass}" />
```

Where `MyClass` is the value of the `x:Key` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was because I was compiling with the CPU set to x64.  For some reason the designer doesn't seem to like this, although I can't figure out why.  If I change to AnyCPU everything works.

I've noticed other problems with x64 configurations as well, such as Unit Tests not working, etc so I guess the environment's support for x64 configurations just isn't up to snuff.